# Pytest fails to collect custom arguments when calling from a file: pytest.main()

Tags: python, pytest

My setup:

**conftest.py**

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
"""avoid adding one letter options like -g"""
parser.addoption('--env',
                 action='store',
                 default='dev',
                 help='Specify environment.')

@fixture(scope="session")
def app_config(get_parameters):
    """
    Returns value from a Config dictionary
    """
    configuration = Config(get_parameters)
    return configuration
```

**config.py**

```
class Config:
def __init__(self, configuration):

    self.url = ENV
```

When I run tests from console everything works fine. But when I'm trying to use pytest.main() it fails to find --env

```
 error: unrecognized arguments: --env
```

Works:

```
python -m pytest -m 'dev' --env local
```

Error:

```
pytest.main(['-m', 'dev', '--env', 'local'])
```

Comment: It's probably not loading your contest.py file. Where is everything located and where are you calling `pytest.main()`?

Comment: It’s all in the same dir as conftest.py

Comment: @Jeff I've checked everything up and it turns out you were right. Even tho the conftest.py was in the same dir as the file containing pytest.main(), pytest was launched from a dir up the tree. So, I had to add the conftest.py dir path to the call to make it work out. Thank you! You really made my day.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to specify the path to the conftest.py dir. Pytest was launched in the root dir that was up one branch in the dir tree, so I had to specify the location of the conftest.py dir in the main() call.

```
exit_code = pytest.main(['conftest_dir/', '-m', 'dev', '--env', 'local'])
```

Dir tree:

```
-- root_dir/ (pytest starts here)
 
    -- conftest_dir/ (contains invoker.py and conftest.py)
```

So I needed to add conftest_dir/ to the call